# Column A contains Column B

Tags: mysql

I have a table:

```
-------------------
col1       |col2   |
--------------------
DaveSmith  |Dave   |
RogerChu   |Roger  |
GaryBee    |Dan    |
```

I would like to select col1 IF it contains the contents of col2....

```
DaveSmith
RogerChu
```

I'm not quite sure how to go about this:

```
SELECT col1 WHERE col1 REGEXP (SELECT something?? )????
SELECT col1 WHERE col1 LOCATE (SELECT something?? , SELECT somethingelse?? )??
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT col1 WHERE col1 REGEXP (COL2)
```